# Sonar-treemap issue

Tags: sonarqube, treemap

I am building a new plugin for sonar 3.0.
I want to display a treemap in this plugin.

I use sonar::treemap class to display treemap.

but i got an error when i click on my plugin page like "we're sorry, but something went wrong".